# Scala, PlayFramework - How to avoid auto escaping character while converting to Json?

Tags: scala, playframework

I have a String:

```
val x = """{foo:"value1", bar:"value2"}"""
```

and I want to convert it into JsString.

```
val converted = JsString(x)
```

Now, if i print `converted`, following result is printed:

```
"{foo:\"value1\", bar:\"value2\"}"
```

However, I don't want the `\` added in the string. Is there any other way avoid this auto escaping without using string.replace?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
println(JsString("""{foo:"value1", bar:"value2"}""").value)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
"{foo:"value1", bar:"value2"}"
```

is not a valid JSON, that's why quotes are escape by `JsString`. Indeed, how would a JSON parser interpret this, if the internal quotes are not escaped?

If you want a (JVM) `String` with the JSON object inside, you already have it. If you want a JSON string, representing a JSON object, you MUST have escaping characters.

If you want the JSON object, you can always use

```
val obj: JsValue = Json.parse("""{foo:"value1", bar:"value2"}""")
```